# How to automatically update the date field through Django Class model

Tags: django, django-models

I am having 2 fields in database named Created_date and updated_date in table and also defined it in django model class and also i am using the default admin console with which user can come and insert or update records.

But i want the above two fields to be inserted automatically and not by inserting or updating through default admin console.

For created_date:It should take the value when the record has been newly inserted and wont change if any of the fields is getting updated.

For Updated_date:It should take the current date whenever record is getting inserted or updated.

Also i want this two fields to be displayable but uneditable..Can i define it through property editable='False'

Regards

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the `auto_now=False` and `auto_now_add=False` field options coming with [DateField/DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#datefield)

```
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: While trying for doing that..I am getting this message:-

You are trying to change the nullable field 'created_on' on wisdomdatavalidation
master to non-nullable without a default; we can't do that (the database needs s
omething to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Ignore for now, and let me handle existing rows with NULL myself (e.g. addin
g a RunPython or RunSQL operation in the new migration file before the AlterFiel
d operation)
 3) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Comment: Well, the message is pretty clear. Right now your `created_on` field in the database is nullable *(`created_on` can be null)*. Running the migration will change it to non-nullable, but this can't be done without fixing all rows with current NULL for `created_on`. You have to chose how you want to handle that... or try to add `null=True` on `created_on`, e.g. `created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)`